# Iteration loop in visual studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++

I need code that calculates user chosen values (amount saved per year, amount to reach and interest in %).

My best guess is that this could be solved with a loop of some sort? So 500 per year * 1.05 (in interest is 5%) = 525 + 500 = 1025 * 1.05.. And so on.

Might not be that hard... But I also need to know how many years it would take to reach a goal, so how many times it would need to loop to reach >= 50 000 for example.
I'v started doing some coding but this is my second thing after "Hello world".
Any help with this at all would be amazing!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float save, goal, intrest;

    cout << "save: ";
    cin >> save;
    cout << "goal: ";
    cin >> goal;
    cout << "intrest: ";
    cin >> intrest;

    float intrest1(ranta / 100 + 1);
    float sum = save * intrest1;

    while (sum < goal) {
        sum + 500 = 
    }

    cout << "summa: " << sum;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: programming uses slightly different syntax than math, so sum + 500 = is not valid, because in programming, you are not doing equasion, but you are assigning value to variable(`a=a+1` is totally valid in programming, not so much as mathematical equasion)

Comment: I use sum as a short for summa that is the swedish word for value :P Thanks for your answer though mate!

Comment: @user3281367 "summa" is the Swedish word for sum. Value is translated as "värde" :)

Comment: please first handle your problem's hand calculation..then try to program it..if you dont know how to express yourself by coding lines..leave us a comment on that line so we can help to write that part..otherwise we will be the ones who does your homework :)

Comment: Yeah, maybe ^^ sorry, my English ain't that good sadly.

Comment: I know how I would like to calculate it though. The problem is that I have no idea how to make a loop that would work in this case :c And how to count the ammount of loops needed and name that value in some way to use it as the ammount of years the saving would take "/ I apoligize again for bad english and grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're right about using a loop to do the calculation, and you're also right that it's not that hard :).

I just edited your code a little, and made it output the total amount you save as well as how many years it takes to reach your goal.

Each iteration, I'm incrementing the number of years and then assigning `sum` to be the amount saved after that year.

Hopefully this helps you get to where you're going.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float save, goal, interest;

    cout << "save: ";
    cin >> save;
    cout << "goal: ";
    cin >> goal;
    cout << "intrest: ";
    cin >> interest;

    float interest1 = interest / 100 + 1;
    float sum = 0;
    int years = 0;

    while (sum < goal) {
      years = years + 1;
      sum = sum * interest1 + save;
    }

    cout << "sum: " << sum << "\n";
    cout << "years: " << years << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :D
The \n is like /br in html right? like pressing enter?
I think I do understand everything though!
 
Thanks you again!

Comment: `\n` is the newline character, which is what you get when you press enter.  A `<br>` tag in HTML creates a line break in the page format, so `<br>` has the same effect on a web page that `\n` does in a text editor or terminal window.  However `<br>` is an HTML tag and `\n` is a character so they are definitely not the same thing.

Comment: aha! "years = years + 1" is to add another year for each loop right?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.  You could also write `years += 1` which means exactly the same thing as `years = years + 1`.

Comment: Thats kinda weird :P Would *= or -= work the same way but with minus and whatever * is in english? :o